# Zip code in checkout pane in mobile displays to far right where users don't find it

Tags: theming, commerce

Theme issue perhaps.

[Commerece kickstart 2](https://drupalcommerce.org/commerce-kickstart-2), sub-theme of Kickstart,
zip code is displayed to the far right on mobile screens (android) and the users can't find it to fill in.

Quick hack is added `clear:both` to class but this effects all displays to have city, state and zip on separate lines.  I'll post a better fix when I have time.

```
.form-item-customer-profile-billing-commerce-customer-address-und-0-postal-code {
   clear:both;
}
```